# Rename column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried the following code. Although I don't get any errors, it did not do it.

```
SELECT * FROM Categories EXEC sp_rename 'Active', CategoriesActive
```

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?
To change the values in the table, or to change the name of a column in the table, or to change the names of multiple columns?

Comment: Can you list what tables / columns you have and what you want to rename them to?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Categories.Active', 'CategoriesActive', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Also see [MSDN documentation for `sp_rename`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx).

Comment: 'Categories.Active' is the representation of 'table.old_column_name' and 'CategoriesActive' is the new column name. works fine.

Answer (score 52):

FOR MSSQL :

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TABLENAME.OLD_COLUMNNAME', 'NEW_COLUMNAME', 'COLUMN';
```

FOR MYSQL : Use ALTER TABLE to do this

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name
```

You can rename a column using a CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name column_definition clause. To do so, specify the old and new column names and the definition that the column currently has. For example, to rename an INTEGER column from a to b, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE a b INTEGER;
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx does not seem to indicate a CHANGE clause to the ALTER TABLE statement

Comment: Sorry I mis-read the question I thought he was referring to MYsql not MSsql!

Will edit accordingly

Comment: actually it it wasn't for the "sp_rename" this very database-specific question would have been database agnostic :)

Answer (score 6):

You **don't** need to use that select in front, and the syntax should be like:

```
EXEC sp_rename 
    @objname = 'Categories.Active', 
    @newname = 'CategoriesActive', 
    @objtype = 'Type_of_your_column'
```