# How can one get visual studio to do a simple change instead of a drop/add when altering database table columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, refactoring, schema-compare

Simply put:

- I am trying to use a visual studio database project to update my sql server database
- I change the names of the table columns by using the refactoring tool
- Once the column names are changed I do a schema comparison before making any final changes to the database
- *However*, I notice that it will drop the column who's name has been changed and then immediately re-adds it (this obviously leads to data loss which I don't want)
- How then can I change the settings in someway to make it do a simple change not a drop/add when changing the names of the columns

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2448127) for renaming columns. Not sure about VS diff code generation, you might have to modify the generated script yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I were to go in and modify each one manually I would also have to modify all 600 references manually as well (that's a literal number by the way), and in most cases that's just for one table. I have 40+ tables to modify, so I really need an automated solution.

Comment: @brykim1 Understood; it's a shame. You'll probably want to find/file a report on Connect or the UserVoice site, and hack something in the meantime. There might be third-party tools to help with that. It could also be that there is a reason why they don't do it automatically, and you'd thus want to know about it.